# Sending parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, transactions, c#-3.0

Where is the problem in my code?

I use a stored procedure and transaction.

For one parameter to be working properly, but when the number of parameters is more than one error occurs.

Where is my problem?

This is my code in C#

```
internal static bool ExecuteNonQueryTransaction(string CommandName, CommandType cmdType, SqlParameter[][] pars)
    {
        int result = 0;
        SqlTransaction tr = null;
        int h = pars.GetLength(0);


        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }


            try
            {
                tr = con.BeginTransaction();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                    cmd.Transaction = tr;
                    cmd.CommandText = CommandName;

                    // cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars);
                    for (int i = 0; i < pars.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars[i]);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    tr.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (tr != null)
                {
                    tr.Rollback();
                }
                //return false;
            }

        }
        return (result > 0);
    }
```

and this my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddNewUserTypePageAccess
(@id_user_type int,
 @id_page_access int)
as
    insert into user_type_page_access(id_user_type, id_page_access)
    values(@id_user_type, @id_page_access) 
    return
```

Thank you for your help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `ExecuteNonQuery();` inside the loop that adds the parameters! Add **all** parameters, and then call `ExecuteNonQuery();` once, with all the parameters in place.

Use this code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
    cmd.Transaction = tr;
    cmd.CommandText = CommandName;

    // cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars);
    for (int i = 0; i < pars.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars[i]);
    }

    // call ExecuteNonQuery only AFTER you've added all the parameters!
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    tr.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I did, but it did not work. i want execute store procedure n-times and all of them most be transaction. i send 2 Parameters n-times